# Is it possible to use explicit register variables in GCC with C++17?

Tags: c++, gcc, assembly, c++17, inline-assembly

I am using [explicit register variables](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Local-Register-Variables.html#Local-Register-Variables) to pass parameters to a raw Linux syscall using registers that don't have [machine-specific constraints](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Machine-Constraints.html) (such as r8, r9, r10 on x86_64) as suggested [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#InputOperands).

```
#include <asm/unistd.h>

#ifdef __i386__
#define _syscallOper "int $0x80"
#define _syscallNumReg "eax"
#define _syscallRetReg "eax"
#define _syscallReg1 "ebx"
#define _syscallReg2 "ecx"
#define _syscallReg3 "edx"
#define _syscallReg4 "esi"
#define _syscallReg5 "edi"
#define _syscallReg6 "ebp"
#define _syscallClob
#else
#define _syscallOper "syscall"
#define _syscallNumReg "rax"
#define _syscallRetReg "rax"
#define _syscallReg1 "rdi"
#define _syscallReg2 "rsi"
#define _syscallReg3 "rdx"
#define _syscallReg4 "r10"
#define _syscallReg5 "r8"
#define _syscallReg6 "r9"
#define _syscallClob "rcx", "r11"
#endif

template <typename Ret = long, typename T1>
Ret syscall(long num, T1 arg1)
{
    register long _num __asm__(_syscallNumReg) = num;
    register T1 _arg1 __asm__(_syscallReg1) = arg1;
    register Ret _ret __asm__(_syscallRetReg);
    __asm__ __volatile__(_syscallOper
        : "=r"(_ret)
        : "r"(_num), "r"(_arg1)
        : _syscallClob);
    return _ret;
}

extern "C" void _start()
{
    syscall(__NR_exit, 0);
}
```

However this feature requires the use of `register` keyword which was deprecated in C++11 and removed in C++17. So when I compile this code with GCC 7 (`-std=c++17 -nostdlib`) it gives me a warning:

```
ISO C++1z does not allow ‘register’ storage class specifier [-Wregister]
```

and it seems to ignore the register allocation and the program segfaults because syscall wasn't called properly. This code however compiles and works fine in Clang 6. *Note: I actually have 6 syscall functions (up to 6 arguments) but only 1-argument version is shown here for the sake of minimal example.*

I realize that `register` keyword by itself wasn't really useful that's why it was removed, but this specific use case seems like an exception to me so it seems unreasonable to remove compiler support for it as well.

I also realize that this use case is compiler-specific (i.e. non-standard), so my question is about compiler support rather then removal from the standard.

Comment: The `-Wregister` note tells you which flags enables the warning. For each such flag, there's one that starts with `no-` and does the opposite, so `-Wno-register` disables it.

Comment: Any reason you don't just wrap the Linux `syscall` function? http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscall.2.html

Comment: @n.m. Well the warning is not the problem, I've already tried disabling it using `-Wno-register` but this just silences the warning and doesn't bring back the intended functionality (i.e. register allocation is still wrong).

Comment: @MichaelPetch, yes, I'm writing a library that doesn't have any external dependencies at all (except for Linux kernel of course) including C library where `syscall` function is implemented. More to the point though, this feature might also be useful in other system programming use cases, not just syscalls.

Comment: gcc produces identical code for this file with -std-c++17, -std-c++14 and -std=c++11, so it isn't clear why c++17 is a game changer for you. The only thing it adds is a suppressible warning.

Comment: MUSL libc already has inline wrapper macros / inline-functions you could use.  e.g. http://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/arch/x86_64/syscall_arch.h.  They use register asm local variables for ARM, or for x86-64 high registers, the same as your code is doing, so would have the same problem if there is a real problem.  BTW, Don't forget the `"memory"` clobber for system calls like `read` or `write`: a pointer input doesn't imply that the pointed-to memory is also an input or output.

Comment: @n.m, I didn't really test this with other standard flags because I'm using C++17 features in my project. But I assumed that this is a C++17 issue because `register` keyword is removed in C++17 standard.

Comment: @r3musn0x: Can you provide a [mcve] of a function that ignores register allocation when inlining this template?  Or instantiating it stand-alone.  e.g. on https://godbolt.org/ with gcc7.3.  Have you tried using `-std=gnu++17` to avoid disabling GNU extensions?

Comment: @PeterCordes, actually -std=gnu++17 didn't work either. I'll try to provide more complete example of the code.

Comment: @MichaelPetch, "he" is insisting on using C++17 and "he" doesn't care which flags to use :)

Comment: @PeterCordes : I'm incorrect, doesn't work with `-std=gnu++17` . Noticed that the code generated actually starts use `rcx`. That's at least my observation `-O0` but it seems okay at `-O1` and above although that appears it might be just by luck? Actually no, the code generated isn't correct. It is as if it ignored the `register` and `asm`

Comment: @PeterCordes, I've updated the example and the flags. I had to remove the 6-argument version of my function because the example uses only 1 argument, however I actually have a whole bunch of these functions up to 6 arguments.

Comment: You could create an external syscall function in assembly or modify the way you do your inline assembly and have it pass arguments 4 5 and 6 into compiler chosen registers and then you put `mov` instructions inside the assembly template that manually move the registers passed to r8, r9, r10. You then use regular constraints to pass rax, rdx, rsi and rdi. This of course would produce less efficient code but it should work dropping the requirement to use `register`

Comment: @MichaelPetch: Huh, yeah it seems to be just plain broken for GCC, even with `-std=gnu++11`, so it's unrelated to the warning.  e.g. gcc8 picks EDX for the first arg, when the register-asm local is specified as RDI. https://godbolt.org/g/aYNQyA.  Looks like a compiler bug.  Clang gets it right.

Comment: @MichaelPetch, thank you for your suggestion, I realize that I can assign these registers directly in my inline assembly, I just wouldn't want to resort to that :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like a GCC bug to me.  The C++17 warning is a red herring.  The code works fine with optimization for me (when compiled with GCC 7), but it breaks at `-O0`.

According to the [documentation for local register variables](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Local-Register-Variables.html), this is not expected, so this is likely a GCC bug.  According to [this bug report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=58118), it is not even related to optimization, but ultimately caused by the use of a template.

I suggest to overload only on the number of system call arguments in the ultimate system call wrapper, and use `long` types for all arguments and the result:

```
inline long syscall_base(long num, long arg1)
{
    register long _num __asm__(_syscallNumReg) = num;
    register long _arg1 __asm__(_syscallReg1) = arg1;
    register long _ret __asm__(_syscallRetReg);
    __asm__ __volatile__(_syscallOper
        : "=r"(_ret)
        : "r"(_num), "r"(_arg1)
        : _syscallClob);
    return _ret;
}

template <typename Ret = long, typename T1>
Ret syscall(long num, T1 arg1)
{
  return (Ret) (syscall_base(num, (long) arg1));
}
```

You'll have to use something nicer for the casts (probably type-indexed conversion functions), and of course you still have to deal with the syscall ABI variance in some other way (x32 has `long long` instead of `long`, and POWER has two return registers instead of one, etc.), but that's also a problem with your original approach.

Comment: The OP's example does *not* work fine for me at `-O3`.  It miscompiles, choosing EDX as the input (see my answer).  And I guess choosing RAX only by chance because it's the first register: changing the `"rax"` string probably wouldn't change the code.  If you were talking about running it, Linux enters `_start` with all the regs zeroed anyway in a static executable, so that's not a sufficient test.

Comment: Thank you for finding the bug report and the fact that it's actually about templates. It is frustrating however that no one seems to care about this one because it's like 5 years old and it's still not fixed.

Comment: @r3musn0x It's a bit worse for one specific clang bug: It's been open for more than a year now and clang still cannot compile libstdc++'s `std::variant`, which is more used than register variables ;)

Answer (score 6):

It appears you've found a GCC bug: GNU register-asm local variables don't work inside template functions.  (clang compiles your example correctly).  Apparently this was already [a known bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=58118), thanks for @Florian for finding it.

`-Wregister` triggering is just a symptom of this first bug: **GNU register-asm local variables don't trigger the warning**.  But in a template, gcc compiles them as they were plain `register int foo = bar;` without the `asm` part of the declaration.  So GCC *thought* you were just using plain `register` variables, not register-asm.

In a regular function, your code compiles fine with no warnings, even with `-std=c++17`.

```
#define T1 unsigned long
#define Ret T1
// template <typename Ret = long, typename T1>
... your code unchanged ...

__asm__ __volatile__(_syscallOper "  #operands in %0, %1, %2"
                ...
```

[On Godbolt with gcc7.3 -O3](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAKxAEZSAbAQwDtRkBSAJgCFufSAZ1QBXYskwgA5NwDMeFsgYisAag6yAwk0EBbAPQiWeQQXQA6BBuwcADAEE7jrvIBmWV6oD6XvLIAcAGw%2BTnIeCpjeggCegshMDAwA8gAOmMTqXFwKBKoAJLYAHv623FyhLuEskV4xcQkMAHIiugBKmMCZXJhMhWUVslU1dfGJ7QTtnWU9fVkDQ1GxowyTtF2YAEaz5Q5hmK4Ri/VjHVzryNvz%2B4e1Sw2Tsuvol7uV19VHy5MALOuCeP1XoN3sM7idgABWJ4AuZAha3Y4rDqBdYbFKA5zAg4fBHLTQMVAbAaYBiCTBXbGgxGpdJdEYNDF7SmfBrNNodLrEXqMt7M3H3TATDllLkvTHw%2BngtYi/A8rE3SVI4BnEX/OUSsFKx4ysVMhWan6c2ilWHikEs8FQkX%2BdXm/nglEigCctr5ivxhM5FzKpCNtDlmBY%2BFcoQc%2Bn0eo%2BABU1kZ/sBquhVAS2E5w5HIuNVDGnARMLoUsw8%2BotARomkWExdJnBSWACLJ1BsX1litVyI52Q2BxZxUQFOdFgtX0x1RMYjAWgASlCAHY%2BA5VEvVMQOiY8xkB94h7pvF4dLofBB7U0WpMp/XVDuNAv7MuV2vTLTR/uJ2sfAejyfVheNA3x5ON5OPeq7AOutJZl4q65B%2Behfoq4znkBi7LrBh5eHuABuqBFngDCYPBmo0hkZRLnIqBpFyQaCKoCiZBCti%2BtwEL0PR5Smve94gF0f7EGUx7QTOKGcao3EivxXg7lOTFZHxWTHgB07ASJokWgwHobDOsi3iBgpiCw3jQchjiznWob2JghQbgZZSaKR2F4EmtQEOOBAQEJJk6cufY%2BI0rReJZhC%2BrYWm3hwplOFI0kMNIEJSKQLDSLY8WoNIdm8PwqjCGIEiZLItDxQQSVRdJADWICyBC5i2LYs5OkEgSzrOELfFwtAQow0jfPFuh0DVCXFaQqVSPFgggIxRVSMl0lwLAMCICgqAFnh6TkJQaDLfhxAgMA/j0AcDAbmNEAbINGwKOO0TSAVpAbdWLAEEkLAMFdU3xVguisMA%2BGDfgq7IAQeCYZgY1vaQlmYMgIh5td8U5CSsOkAQxB4L1UgFdFX0oPw/CMHgGxjZA0kUYDTagwAtKY6B/pwGW8LQs6qOTADqDRM0ksijaI4iSNOnVSHFA1g8NxSBOTgS/MAyDIKo/jmGsEC4IQJB5axmhLSkK0kS406qOlfC8IVxVTmVFW0PLNXfIEWS1bObWBPz3WkL1gSyNVsi2B7Xuez7XDfELyVDdIo3jUjxukLNC2iAQKTQ2tEAbZrW10OD%2BBENt9AAO5ciksPRbF8WJcL0hyGsmeEAgqii%2BLkvS7L8tG29JukAgPRYNt7mOz1FWBOYTqBP3g8D8PTqzg7ReB8NIcTcbpv5eYgQQkEdX1U6tB%2BxCsgOzFUicwHKXB2HTcR/NkcQEgida/Hl/J0oX2BP1B1HZQp1g%2BdlbEK9N13YGj3Pa9gcPpfR%2Bujd6eB/qA2BqDQOEMoYw1AeQB6CMEHI1RnnRgWNaYGwEAwfGhNO4kzwGTaQlMzB/gTCIHG9NGYszZuTDmXMcq83zgLQug0RZBBrqoO%2BbBVC91sNVVQis04q1Lr6dWm1aRyC4BefW/BG7TTnm7WQKjVFqLUV3Z2IAGL7yDiNIQodJrTRPvAc%2BIBo6xwINfDWWsQBcFTsrDOpBs5MFzqAlhgsJ4HxkC4M45cCCV2rhLbhzBeH8OqgokqLc27pEoCwp2vUdFeL0dPI%2BijSDlRUeYdROTVH8z3skqeaSok7y4N3Y0jFCmHyMVE4GxB/hNhAN8IAA%3D%3D%3D):

```
_start:
    movl    $60, %eax
    xorl    %edx, %edx
    syscall  #operands in %rax, %rax, %edx
    ret
```

But clang6.0 doesn't have this bug, and we get:

```
_start:                                 # @_start
    movl    $60, %eax
    xorl    %edi, %edi
    syscall #operands in %rax, %rax, %edi
    retq
```

**Notice the asm comment I appended to your template (with C++ string-literal concatenation).  We can just get the compiler to tell us what it thinks it's doing, instead of having to puzzle things out.**

(Mostly posting this answer to discuss that debugging technique; Florian's answer already covers the specifics of this actual case.)

---

#### Instead of templates, you can use MUSL's existing portable headers:

It's a C library, so it might need a bit of extra casting to keep a C++ compiler happy.  Or avoiding use of temporary expressions as lvalues, in the ARM headers.

But it should take care of most of the issues Florian pointed out.  It has a permissive license, so you can just copy its syscall wrapper headers into your project.  They work without linking against the rest of MUSL, and are truly inline.

http://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/arch/x86_64/syscall_arch.h  is the x86-64 version.